# How to download apache tomcat 6.0.35.

Tags: apache, tomcat

The website is linking me to this page http://ir.ucc.edu.gh/docs/setup.html#Windows    .I need this to work in eclipse indigo. please help. :(

Comment: What, exactly, do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can download at http://apache.dattatec.com/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.44/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.44.zip

There is a procedure for adding a tomcat servers: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html

Hope it helps.